# Generating multiple geom_smooth lines of data samples

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggproto

Attempting to build a new geom function here that will take a sample of points from a dataset by group, and fit a number of local regressions through the individual subsets. This would generate multiple local regression lines as samples of a full dataset. In the end generating something akin to this:[image]

Though I'm continuing to get errors with the function I've built below (with reprex). Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

geom_mline <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "mline",
                         position = "identity", show.legend = NA,
                         inherit.aes = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE,
                         SPAN = .9, N_size = 50, N_LOESS = 50, ...) {
  layer(
    geom = geomMline,
    mapping = mapping,
    data = data,
    stat = stat,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(SPAN=SPAN,
                  N_size=N_size,
                  N_LOESS=N_LOESS,
                  ...)
  )
}

geomMline <- ggproto("geomMline", GeomLine,
                       required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                       default_aes = aes(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, alpha = NA)
)

stat_mline <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "line",
                         position = "identity", show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
                         SPAN = .9, N_size = 50, N_LOESS = 50, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatMline,
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    geom = geom,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(SPAN=SPAN,
                  N_size=N_size,
                  N_LOESS=N_LOESS,
                  ...
    )
  )
}

StatMline <- ggproto("StatMline", Stat,

                       required_aes = c("x", "y"),

                       compute_group = function(self, data, scales, params,
                                                SPAN = .9, N_size = 50, N_LOESS = 50) {

                         tf <- tempfile(fileext=".png")
                         png(tf)
                         plot.new()
                         colnames(data) <- c("x", "variable", "y")
                         LOESS_DF <- data.frame(y = seq(min(data$x), 
                                                               max(data$x), 
                                                               length.out = 50))

                         for(i in 1:N_LOESS){
                           # sample N_size points
                           df_sample <- sample_n(data, N_size)
                           # fit a loess
                           xx <- df_sample$x
                           yy <- df_sample$y
                           tp_est <- loess(yy ~ xx , span = SPAN) 
                           # predict accross range of x using loess model
                           loess_vec <- data.frame(
                             predict(tp_est, newdata = 
                                       data.frame(xx = seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), length.out = 500))))
                           colnames(loess_vec) <- as.character(i)
                           # repeat x times
                           LOESS_DF <- cbind(LOESS_DF,loess_vec)
                           #str(LOESS_DF)
                         }

                         invisible(dev.off())
                         unlink(tf)
                         data.frame(reshape2::melt(LOESS_DF, id = "y"))




                       }
)

# dummy data
library(reshape2)


x  <- seq(1,1000,1)
y1 <- rnorm(n = 1000,mean = x*2^1.1, sd = 200)
y2 <- rnorm(n = 1000,mean = x*1, sd = 287.3)
y3 <- rnorm(n = 1000,mean = x*1.1, sd = 100.1)

data <- data.frame(x , y1, y2, y3)

data <- melt(data, id.vars = "x")
str(data)

ggplot(data,aes(x,value,group = variable, color = va

riable))+geom_point()

    ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = value, group=variable, color = variable)) +
  #geom_point(color="black") +
  #geom_smooth(se=FALSE, linetype="dashed", size=0.5) +
  #stat_mline(SPAN = .2, N_size = 50, N_LOESS = 5)
  geom_mline(SPAN = .2, N_size = 50, N_LOESS = 5)

    #data <- subset(data, variable == "y2")
```

[image]

Comment: Comment appeared to be removed after edit. Something like: ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = value, group=variable, color = variable)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(se=FALSE) Does get me close, but I want to draw multiple local regression based on subsets.

Comment: I removed my original comment when I realized (assuming I understand your question) that you want to draw samples from the data and plot regression lines through each sample. I've added an answer that hopefully addresses your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the existing `geom_smooth` geom and use `lapply` to generate `geom_smooth` calls from multiple random samples from the original data frame. For example:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(x = runif(100, 0, 10))
dat$y = 2*dat$x - 0.5*dat$x^2 - 5 + rnorm(100, 0, 5)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  lapply(1:10, function(i) {
    geom_smooth(data=dat[sample(1:nrow(dat), 20), ], se=FALSE)
    })
```

Or, keeping it all in the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  map(1:10, ~geom_smooth(data=dat[sample(1:nrow(dat), 20), ], se=FALSE))
```

[image]

Here's a way to plot the quantiles within ggplot. I'm not sure if it's possible to get `stat_quantile` to plot a ribbon. To get that, you might have to calculate the quantile regression outside of ggplot and add use `geom_ribbon` to add the values.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_quantile(quantiles=c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9), formula=y ~ poly(x, 2), 
                aes(color=factor(..quantile..), size=factor(..quantile..))) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","red")) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(1,2,1)) +
  labs(colour="Quantile") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE), size=FALSE) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: This works really well for now. Thank you! Do you think there is an easy way to extend this to then plot the quantiles of the predictions at each x value. i.e. something like the picture added to the answer?

Comment: The above picture is plotting the approximately the 90% quantiles of the spread of the predicted values.

Comment: Second figure appears to be plotting the quantiles of the observed values? Rather than plotting the values of the quantiles of the multiple local regression's predictions?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're looking for. What does the shaded area of your second plot represent?

Comment: Shaded area is the upper and lower quantiles (90%) of the predicted values of the multiple local regressions. For example if five hundred lines are fit, each x-value has 500 predicted values from which quantiles can be estimated.